# How to wait for a multiply nested requests before creating another requests?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, grand-central-dispatch

I have a Refresh Control. And when I pull it down I make 2 nested requests like that:

```
  httpClient.fetchCurrentWeather(...
    httpclient.fetchAnotherPartOfWeather(...
      delegate.showWeather(...)
    )
   )
```

I want to wait for first group to complete before calling another, because when i do like this i get my views blink because of many callback value updates.

upd:
i do calls in interactor:

```
func retreiveCurrentDailyWeatherForecast() {
        guard let lat = locations?.first?.coordinate.latitude,
            let lon = locations?.first?.coordinate.longitude
            else { return }

        httpClient.fetchCurrentWeather(
            parameters: ["lat": lat,
                         "lon": lon, "units": "metric"],
            completionHandler: { dailyWeatherResult in
                switch dailyWeatherResult {
                case .success(let dailyWeatherResponse):
                    self.httpClient.fetchCurrentHourlyWeather(
                        parameters: ["lat": lat,
                                     "lon": lon, "units": "metric"],
                        completionHandler: { dailyWeeklyHourlyResult in
                            switch dailyWeeklyHourlyResult {
                            case .success(let dailyWeeklyHourlyResponse):
                                let weatherForecast =
                                    self.modelConverter.convertWeatherForecast(dailyWeatherResponse,
                                                                               dailyWeeklyHourlyResponse)
                                self.didRetreieveWeatherForecastFromNetwork(weatherForecast)
                            case .failure(let err):
                                print(err)
                            }
                    })
                case .failure(let err):
                    print(err)
                }
        })
    }

    func didRetreieveWeatherForecastFromNetwork(_ weatherForecast: WeatherForecast?) {
        if let weatherForecast = weatherForecast {
            self.presenter.didRetreiveWeatherForecast(weatherForecast)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you're not showing enough of your code because what you're showing would do what you say you want. Are you doing the code you showed over multiple values like in a loop?

Comment: Second that. Can you show more of your code? Show the entirety of the callbacks content.

Comment: @rs7, i updated the qestion.

Comment: @AdamPro13, yes, please see my code above.

Comment: @Alexander the statements that update your UI and are contained in a completion handler need to be executed on the main thread. Which functions update your UI? Probably the didRetrieveWeather.. ?

Comment: @AdamPro13, yeah, it's a callback series (interactor -> presenter -> view controller) and completion handler executes in main thread (alamofire library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you won't be needing anything too advanced. You just need to main a `Boolean` (example: `isRequestIncomplete`) to check if the response for the previous request was received. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
if isRequestIncomplete { return }
isRequestIncomplete = true
httpClient.fetchCurrentWeather(...
    httpclient.fetchAnotherPartOfWeather(...
      isRequestIncomplete = false
      delegate.showWeather(...)
    )
   )
```

Comment: You don't need a boolean to check if the request is complete. Completion handlers are executed asynchronously.

Comment: And how are you going to tell if the completion handlers got called?

Comment: Completion handlers are either going to get executed sequentially or one of them is going to throw an error. So the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @Frankenstein, i think i can mark your answer as solution because now i get these calls called only 2 times when call function.

Comment: I hope you understood the logic I'm trying to convey here.